# WP custom post type loop using ACF not showing in category pages footer

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type "suppliers" who's sole purpose is to display a series of supplier logos in the footer. This works fine on every page except the category pages?

It uses the advanced custom fields plugin for a logo and the suppliers url.

My code is:

```
<?php $suppliers_loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'suppliers', 'posts_per_page' => 7 ) ); ?>
<?php if ($suppliers_loop->have_posts()): while ( $suppliers_loop->have_posts() ) : $suppliers_loop->the_post(); 
    $image = get_field('image');?>
    <a href="<?php echo(get_field('suppliers_url'))?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $image['url'];?>" title="<?php echo $image['title'];?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'];?>"/>
    </a>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Which is outputting:

```
    <a href="">
        <img src="" title="" alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="">
        <img src="" title="" alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="">
        <img src="" title="" alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="">
        <img src="" title="" alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="">
        <img src="" title="" alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="">
        <img src="" title="" alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="">
        <img src="" title="" alt=""/>
    </a>
```

So it's looping but just not displaying the content?

Comment: Can you put `print_r( get_field_object('image') );` in the loop and post what returns.

Comment: nothing is returned.

Comment: OK, at first blush it sounds like you might be calling the wrong field name. Try `print_r( get_fields() );` in the loop: that should output *all* the fields for each post. Then we can see what's been registered and figure out what isn't working.

Comment: Sorry, I might not have been particularly comprehensive with my last answer. `print_r( get_field('image') );` returns the field array on pages where the loop is functioning, however, on the pages such as category, despite all pages use the same footer file, nothing is returned.

Comment: This is the returned array (shortened to fit in the word count).
`Array ( [ID] => 1547 [id] => 1547 [title] => xxx [filename] => image.jpg [url] => /uploads/2016/11/image.jpg [alt] => xxx [author] => 2 [description] => [caption] => [name] => supplierlogos7-2 [date] => 2016-11-22 14:25:52 [modified] => 2016-11-22 14:57:12 [mime_type] => image/jpeg [type] => image [icon] => /wp-includes/images/media/default.png [width] => 110 [height] => 60 [sizes] => Array ( [thumbnail] => /uploads/2016/11/image.jpg [thumbnail-width] => 960 [thumbnail-height] => 640  ) )`

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part about it not working on category pages. Can you check that your category templates are calling `wp_reset_postdata()` after the main loop/before your suppliers loop.